# Whats wrong with my code? I want to find the row length of a specific row

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I cannot get my code to identity a specific row and tell me its length. When I run this, it returns "undefined"
Ideally, I want to be able to call specific cells in specific rows in order to put the day number that goes in each cell, but right now I am just trying to return the length of the row.

```
   document.getElementById("Show Calendar").addEventListener( 'click',      function calendarMaker() 
{

  var table = document.getElementById("Calendar");
  var date = new Date();
  var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
  var currentDay = date.getDay();

  var months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

 var days =["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

var row =0;

var cell =0;

  for( var i=0; i<6;i++)
 {
  row = table.insertRow(i);

for(var a=0; a<7;a++)
{
  cell = row.insertCell(a);

  cell.contentEditable = true;

   for(b=0;b<7;b++)
   {
      if(i===0 &&a==b)
      {
        cell.innerHTML = days[b];

    }
  }
 }
}



 var x = document.getElementById("Calendar").rows[0].length; 
document.getElementById("rowCount").innerHTML = x;




});
```

Comment: You cannot use spaces in your ID. Therefore  `document.getElementById("Show Calendar")` doesn't make sense. Change it to `showCalendar` or similar instead (also in HTML of course).

Comment: perhaps you meant `rows.length` (number of rows in the table) or `rows[0].cells.length` (number of cells in row 0)

Comment: @BramVanroy - spaces are valid in ID's - not recommended, makes CSS, and querySelector all kinds of difficult

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you for solving that problem! Now, how do I get cell 0 in row 1 to display text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice, x is undefined. You are trying to access length of first row when you type

```
var x = document.getElementById("Calendar").rows[0].length;
```

That is because you are accessing length of first row.

instead, you should use

```
var x = document.getElementById("Calendar").rows.length;
```

You can then access each cell in row like following

```
 var x = document.getElementById("Calendar").rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    var row = document.getElementById("Calendar").rows.item(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
      var col = row.cells.item(j);
      col.innerText = i * j;
    }
  }
```

See working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/21ukrzj6/2/)